# Can Python's functool's reduce work with functions in the iterable?

Tags: python, reduce

I'm trying to figure out how to return a function in Python. However, I don't know if the issue is with `reduce` or with my code. What I currently have is this:

#### Code:

```
def combine(*args):
    from functools import reduce
    def closure(val):
        return reduce( (lambda x, f: f(x)), args, val)
    return closure


def first(array):
    return array[0]
def shift(array):
    return array[1:]
fifth = combine(first, shift, shift, shift, shift)
print(fifth([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) # should return 5
```

However, I get the error message:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

What's causing this?

Answer (score 2):

As it is defined in your question, `fifth(x)` is the same as:

```
fifth(x) = shift(shift(shift(shift(first(x)))))
```

Now, if `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`, then

```
first(x) = 1
```

But that means that

```
shift(first(x)) = first(x)[1:] = 1[1:]
```

But as the error message tells us, `1` is not subscriptable.

---

I assume what's really causing this is a misconception about the order `reduce` works. It works from left to right, so the leftmost function given is applied first (i.e., innermost):

```
combine(a, b, c)(x) = c(b(a(x)))
```

If you instead wanted `a(b(c(x)))`, you would have to either pass them to `combine` in the reverse order, or modify your defintion of `combine` so that it reverses the order of the arguments for you:

```
def combine(*args):
  from functools import reduce
  def closure(val):
    return reduce( (lambda x, f: f(x)), reversed(args), val)
  return closure
```